# Is there a way to upgrade coffeescript package in meteor? If there is, how?

Tags: meteor

The native package coffeescript in meteor is kind of old which does not support one of the important functionality that I encountered: string interpolation in object literal keys like following

```
key = getKeyFunc()
obj =
  "#{key}": value
```

I know there is some work around like:

```
obj = {}
obj[key] = value
```

However, I am just wondering is there a way to update the package in order to let it support string interpolation in object literal key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version on the [devel branch](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/coffeescript/package.js) is using `1.9.2` so the easiest solution would be to wait until meteor [1.1.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#in-progress-v111) is released (which should be soon).

If you can't wait, you may be able to copy the entire [package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/coffeescript) into your app's `/packages` directory to upgrade immediatley.